# Joomla, Registered Access only for registered users

Tags: joomla

When I create an article and I put the access for it Registered, which means only the registered user can see it, I mean i have to be logged to see the file, in my case even i dont log in , it still shows me that article with Registered access, How come, isnt it supposed to be only for logged users to be viewed Register Access Permission set.

I think before was working but I don't know what i changed and now its making problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of article just go the Menu option and then set the corresponding Menu for Registered user. I hope it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: It doesnt work in that case too :S, its strange isnt it?
There must be something i have changed in administratoin panel and i dont know.

Comment: I have checked at my end it is working fine. I am using joomla 2.5. I just selected one Menu for Registered User, then whenever I am trying to access that it is asking for login. Can you test the same process in other setup joomla ?

Comment: this sentense helped me "Can you test the same process in other setup joomla ?" and i solved it now :d